# Passing extra parameters to release:prepare, but not to release:perform

Tags: maven-2, gwt, hudson

When preparing the release of a Maven 2 project which includes a GWT module, `mvn -B release:prepare release:perform` builds the GWT module twice, which takes up most of the time of the build.

Running a full GWT build is not necessary when executing `release:prepare`, a validate-only build is enough. This would be achieved by specifying the `-Dgwt.validateOnly=true` flag on the command line, but the command line arguments are passed to a single execution when using the Maven 2 Release plugin plugin under Hudson.

How can I pass the `-Dgwt.validateOnly` flag to `release:prepare` but not to `release:perform`?

Answer (score 1):

Do it yourself and create two steps.

1. `mvn -B release:prepare -Dgwt.validateOnly=true`
2. `mvn -B release:perform`

**EDIT:** Just read the documentation of the M2 Release Plugin. I suggest to use the standard [Release Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Release+Plugin) or the [Batch Task Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Batch+Task+Plugin) .

Comment: Thanks, that would solve it, but I would need to create another Hudson job, and that would not be acceptable. I'd rather wait 5 minutes more.